# Sql server Job starts one month early

Tags: sql-server, job-scheduling, sql-job

My job scheduler has a behavior I can't understand.

It is schedule to fire in the following conditions:

***Occurs every 3 month(s) on day 1 of that month at 00:00:00. Schedule will be used starting on 30/09/2015.***

So I expected to see it launched next july at midnight and this OK for years.

But it started this night (1st of june).

The script and database have been completely reinstalled on next 5th of may for a migration.

I am using SQL Server 2012 on an on premises server.

Does anybody has an explanation?

Thank you

Comment: You've set the date for September, it will start on the 1st of that month and run every three months. It will run on the 1st of Sep, Dec, Mar, Jun i believe. At least, that's my understanding.

Comment: yes I think you are right, I made a mistake by computing the dates

Comment: Why you assume that it was automatically started ?